# How do I speed up counting rows in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-performance

We need to count the number of rows in a PostgreSQL table. In our case, no conditions need to be met, and it would be perfectly acceptable to get a row estimate if that significantly improved query speed.

Basically, we want `select count(id) from <table>` to run as fast as possible, even if that implies not getting exact results.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: @PavelStehule thanks for that link, I didn't know changes in PG9.2 improved performance for count()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way to discover the row count of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

For a very quick estimate:

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'my_table';
```

There are several caveats, though. For one, `relname` is not necessarily unique in `pg_class`. There can be multiple tables with the same `relname` in multiple schemas of the database. To be unambiguous:

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass;
```

If you do not schema-qualify the table name, a cast to `regclass` observes the current [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) to pick the best match. And if the table does not exist (or cannot be seen) in any of the schemas in the `search_path` you get an error message. See [*Object Identifier Types* in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html).

The cast to `bigint` formats the `real` number nicely, especially for big counts.

Also, `reltuples` can be more or less out of date. There are ways to make up for this to some extent. See this later answer with new and improved options:

- **[Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table/7945274#7945274)**

And a query on [`pg_stat_user_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE) is many times slower (though still much faster than full count), as that's a view on a couple of tables.

Comment: Nice +1. Any idea on how we can speed up counting rows in postgres having search query?

Comment: @varunvlalan: Please ask the question as question (with the necessary detail to make it clear). Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: This query gives an estimate. If I would like to build a reports where I need exact count of records, that can be run on table of several hundreds of thousands records? 've seen that postgre take up to 13s for counting 20000 records!! I can believe it

Comment: @Giox: I can't believe it either. 13s for 20k rows is far beyond normal - indicating a problem in your DB. Shouldn't take more than a couple of ms. Please ask a *question* providing necessary details. You can always link to this one for context. Comments are not the place. You can drop a short comment here ([or maybe here?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)) to link to the related question and get my attention.

Comment: This query gave me 415K, however COUNT(*) returns 8M.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: This can happen  immediately after big writes to the table, or if `autovacuum` is not running or badly misconfigured  or for temporary tables, which are not covered by autovacuum. Run `ANALYZE tbl;` and then try again. Then find the reason why the table wasn't analyzed automatically. Follow the linked answer above for more.

Answer (score 15):

Count is slow for big tables, so you can get a close estimate this way:

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate 
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relname='tableName';
```

and its extremely fast, results are not float, but still a close estimate.

- `reltuples` is a column from `pg_class` table, it holds data about "number of rows in the table. This is only an estimate used by the planner. It is updated by VACUUM, ANALYZE, and a few DDL commands such as CREATE INDEX" (manual)
- The catalog `pg_class` catalogs tables and most everything else that has columns or is otherwise similar to a table. This includes indexes (but see also pg_index), sequences, views, composite types, and some kinds of special relation (manual)
- "Why is "SELECT count(*) FROM bigtable;" slow?" : http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_.22SELECT_count.28.2A.29_FROM_bigtable.3B.22_slow.3F

Comment: nice, the ::bigint part avoids some overflow with tables size > 4B or some threshold like that, thanks!

Comment: is it possible to add where clause if I want to ?

Answer (score 7):

Aside from running COUNT() on an indexed field (which hopefully 'id' is) - the next best thing would be to actually cache the row count in some table using a trigger on INSERT.  Naturally, you'll be checking the cache instead.

For an approximation you can try this (from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate):

```
select reltuples from pg_class where relname='tablename';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get an estimate from the system table "pg_stat_user_tables".

```
select schemaname, relname, n_live_tup 
from pg_stat_user_tables 
where schemaname = 'your_schema_name'
and relname = 'your_table_name';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can ask for the exact value of the count in the table by simply using trigger AFTER INSERT OR DELETE 
Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE  tcounter(id serial primary key,table_schema text, table_name text, count serial);

insert into tcounter(table_schema, table_name,count) select 'my_schema', 'my_table', count(*) from my_schema.my_table;
```

and use trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ex_count()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
      UPDATE tcounter set count = count + 1 where table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT and table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT;
    ELSIF  (TG_OP='DELETE') THEN
      UPDATE tcounter set count = count - 1 where table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT and table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT;
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_counter  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
  ON my_schema.my_table  FOR EACH ROW  EXECUTE PROCEDURE ex_count();
```

And ask for count

```
select * from tcounter where table_schema =  'my_schema' and table_name = 'my_table'
```

it means you select count(*) once for initialize first record

Answer (score 0):

If your database is small, you can get an estimate of all your tables like @mike-sherrill-cat-recall suggested. This command will list all the tables though.

```
SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;
```

Output would be something like this:

```
 schemaname |      relname       | n_live_tup
------------+--------------------+------------
 public     | items              |      21806
 public     | tags               |      11213
 public     | sessions           |       3269
 public     | users              |        266
 public     | shops              |        259
 public     | quantities         |         34
 public     | schema_migrations  |         30
 public     | locations          |          8
(8 rows)
```

Comment: My thank you from many years later. The result from this query is more accurate than 
`SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class WHERE relname='table'`