# fastest way of having a number of rows of a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

To have the exact number of rows of a table `t` I actually run the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM t;
```

Is there a faster way to do this ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table

Answer (score 0):

You can use async routine increment add the count number to other table.
or if the table DML tps is little , can  use sync routine like trigger.
NOTE:
async routine shold attention concurrency problem, when get increment data from the t table.
EXP : 
1. trigger

```
postgres=# create table a(id serial4 primary key, info text, crt_time timestamp(0) default now());
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "a_id_seq" for serial column "a.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "a_pkey" for table "a"
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table cnt_a(id int primary key, cnt int);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "cnt_a_pkey" for table "cnt_a"
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into cnt_a select generate_series(0,1000),0;
INSERT 0 1001
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tg_insert_a()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
  m_id int;
  rm numeric;
begin
  select max(id),random() into m_id,rm from cnt_a;
  update cnt_a set cnt=cnt+1 where id=(rm*m_id)::int;
  return null;
end;
$function$;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tg_delete_a()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
  m_id int;
  rm numeric;
begin
  select max(id),random() into m_id,rm from cnt_a;
  update cnt_a set cnt=cnt-1 where id=(rm*m_id)::int;
  return null;
end;
$function$;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tg_truncate_a()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
begin
  update cnt_a set cnt=0 where not cnt=0;
  return null;
end;
$function$;
create trigger tg1 after insert on a for each row execute procedure tg_insert_a();
create trigger tg2 after delete on a for each row execute procedure tg_delete_a();
create trigger tg3 after truncate on a for each statement execute procedure tg_truncate_a();
pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> cat insert.sql 
insert into a (info) values ('test');
pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> pgbench -M prepared -r -n -f ./insert.sql -h $PGDATA -p 1919 -U postgres -T 60 -c 16 -j 4 postgres
transaction type: Custom query
scaling factor: 1
query mode: prepared
number of clients: 16
number of threads: 4
duration: 60 s
number of transactions actually processed: 1831418
tps = 30514.831839 (including connections establishing)
tps = 30522.057886 (excluding connections establishing)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
        0.522411        insert into a (info) values ('test');
postgres=# select count(*) from a;
  count  
---------
 1755964
(1 row)
Time: 285.491 ms
postgres=# select sum(cnt) from cnt_a ;
   sum   
---------
 1755964
(1 row)
Time: 0.689 ms
```

1. async count exp :

   -- # TEST TABLE :

   create table log 
   (
     id serial primary key, 
     xid int8 default txid_current() not null, 
     c1 int not null, 
     c2 int not null, 
     c3 int not null, 
     c4 text not null, 
     crt_time timestamp default now()
   );
   create index idx_log_1 on log(xid);

   ```
   -- # COUTN TABLE
   create table log_c1_cnt_day (c1 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c1,stat_time));
   create table log_c1_cnt_week (c1 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c1,stat_time));
   create table log_c1_cnt_month (c1 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c1,stat_time));
   create table log_c1_cnt_year (c1 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c1,stat_time));

   -- # COUNT TABLE 2
   create table log_c2_c3_cnt_day (c2 int, c3 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c2,c3,stat_time));
   create table log_c2_c3_cnt_week (c2 int, c3 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c2,c3,stat_time));
   create table log_c2_c3_cnt_month (c2 int, c3 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c2,c3,stat_time));
   create table log_c2_c3_cnt_year (c2 int, c3 int, cnt int8, stat_time text, primary key(c2,c3,stat_time));

   -- TEST DATA
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values (1,1,1,1);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values (2,2,2,2);

   -- 
   digoal=# select * from log;
    id |    xid    | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |          crt_time          
   ----+-----------+----+----+----+----+----------------------------
     1 | 480125659 |  1 |  1 |  1 | 1  | 2013-04-21 20:55:45.907713
     2 | 480125660 |  2 |  2 |  2 | 2  | 2013-04-21 20:55:46.286933
   (2 rows)
   ```

   -- # aysnc count function

   ```
   create table log_read 
   (
   tablename name not null, 
   xid int8 not null, 
   xip int8[], 
   xip_res int8[],  
   mod_time timestamp, 
   primary key (tablename)
   );
   insert into log_read values ('log', 0, null, null, now());


   create or replace function analyze_log(v_limit int) returns void as $$
   declare
     v_advisory_xact_lock int8 := null;  

     v_xid_snap txid_snapshot := null;  
     v_xmin int8 := null;  
     v_xmax int8 := null;  
     v_xip int8[] := null;  

     v_log_read_log_xid int8 := null;  
     v_log_read_log_xid_update int8 := null;  

     v_log_read_log_xip int8[] := null;  
     v_log_read_log_xip_do int8[] := null;  
     v_log_read_log_xip_update int8[] := null;  
     v_log_read_log_xip_res int8[] := null;  
     v_log_read_log_xip_res_update int8[] := null;  

     v_log log[] := null;  
     v_log_doxip log[] := null;  

   begin
     if v_limit <=0 then
       raise notice 'please ensure v_limit > 0 .';
       return;
     end if;

     v_advisory_xact_lock := 1;
     if not pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(v_advisory_xact_lock) then
       raise notice 'Another function is calling, this call will exit.';
       return;
     end if;

     v_xid_snap := txid_current_snapshot();
     v_xmin := txid_snapshot_xmin(v_xid_snap);
     v_xmax := txid_snapshot_xmax(v_xid_snap);
     select array_agg(t) into v_xip from txid_snapshot_xip(v_xid_snap) g(t);

     select xid,xip,xip_res into v_log_read_log_xid,v_log_read_log_xip,v_log_read_log_xip_res from log_read where tablename='log';
     if not found then
       raise notice 'log_read no log entry. please add it in log_read table first.';
       return;
     end if;

     select max(xid) into v_log_read_log_xid_update from (select xid from log where xid > v_log_read_log_xid and xid < v_xmax and xid not in (select * from unnest(v_xip) union all select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip_res)) order by xid limit v_limit) t;
     if v_log_read_log_xid_update is not null then
       raise notice '取log1';
       select array_agg(log) into v_log from (select log from log where xid > v_log_read_log_xid and xid<=v_log_read_log_xid_update and xid not in (select * from unnest(v_xip) union all select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip_res)) order by xid) t;
     else 
       v_log_read_log_xid_update := v_log_read_log_xid;
     end if;

     select array_agg(i) into v_log_read_log_xip_do from (select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip) i except select * from unnest(v_xip))t where i is not null;
     select array_agg(i) into v_log_read_log_xip_update from 
     (  select i from (select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip) i union all select * from unnest(v_xip)
        except select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip_do)) t where i is not null group by i ) t;
     select array_agg(i) into v_log_read_log_xip_res_update from (select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip_res) i union select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip) union select * from unnest(v_xip))t where i>v_log_read_log_xid_update;
     select array_agg(log) into v_log_doxip from log where xid in (select * from unnest(v_log_read_log_xip_do));

     update log_read set 
       xip=v_log_read_log_xip_update, 
       xid=v_log_read_log_xid_update, 
       xip_res=v_log_read_log_xip_res_update,
       mod_time=now() 
     where tablename='log';
     -- raise notice 'log_read.oldxip(log): %.', v_log_read_log_xip;
     -- raise notice 'log_read.newxip(log): %.', v_log_read_log_xip_update;
     -- raise notice 'log_read.newxipres(log): %.', v_log_read_log_xip_res_update;

     perform stat_log_c1(v_log);
     perform stat_log_c1(v_log_doxip);

   return;
   end;
   $$ language plpgsql;

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.stat_log_c1(v_log log[])
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS $function$
   declare
     v_stat_time text;
     v_c1 int;
     v_cnt int8;
   begin
     for v_stat_time, v_c1, v_cnt in select to_char(crt_time, 'yyyymmdd'), c1 , count(*) from (select ((unnest(v_log)::log)).*) t group by to_char(crt_time, 'yyyymmdd'), c1 loop
       perform 1 from log_c1_cnt_day where c1=v_c1 and stat_time=v_stat_time;
       if not found then
         insert into log_c1_cnt_day(c1, cnt, stat_time) values (v_c1, v_cnt, v_stat_time);
       else
         update log_c1_cnt_day set cnt=cnt+v_cnt where c1=v_c1 and stat_time=v_stat_time;
       end if;
     end loop;
   end;
   $function$;

   truncate log;
   truncate log_c1_cnt_day;
   update log_read set xid=0, xip=null, xip_res=null;

   -- pgbench script
   cat ins.sql 
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);

   -- # pgbench
   pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> pgbench -M prepared -f ./ins.sql -r -n -h $PGDATA -U postgres -T 60 -c 8 -j 2
   transaction type: Custom query
   scaling factor: 1
   query mode: prepared
   number of clients: 8
   number of threads: 2
   duration: 60 s
   number of transactions actually processed: 2887271
   tps = 48121.007692 (including connections establishing)
   tps = 48131.903512 (excluding connections establishing)
   statement latencies in milliseconds:
           0.164881        insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);

   pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> cat analyze.sh 
   #!/bin/bash
   for ((i=0;i<100;i++))
   do
   psql -c "select * from analyze_log(1);"
   psql -c "select * from analyze_log(1000000);"
   done
   # 调用analyze.sh

   digoal=# select c1,count(*),to_char(crt_time,'yyyymmdd') from log group by c1,to_char(crt_time,'yyyymmdd') order by c1;
    c1 | count  | to_char  
   ----+--------+----------
     0 | 140071 | 20130421
     1 | 282303 | 20130421
     2 | 281499 | 20130421
     3 | 281339 | 20130421
     4 | 282008 | 20130421
     5 | 281871 | 20130421
     6 | 282954 | 20130421
     7 | 281855 | 20130421
     8 | 281560 | 20130421
     9 | 281516 | 20130421
    10 | 140456 | 20130421
   (11 rows)
   digoal=# select * from log_c1_cnt_day where cnt<>0 order by c1;
    c1 |  cnt   | stat_time 
   ----+--------+-----------
     0 | 140071 | 20130421
     1 | 282303 | 20130421
     2 | 281499 | 20130421
     3 | 281339 | 20130421
     4 | 282008 | 20130421
     5 | 281871 | 20130421
     6 | 282954 | 20130421
     7 | 281855 | 20130421
     8 | 281560 | 20130421
     9 | 281516 | 20130421
    10 | 140456 | 20130421
   (11 rows)


   cat ins.sql
   begin;
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   end;
   begin;
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   rollback;
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   insert into log (c1,c2,c3,c4) values(round(random()*10),1,2,3);
   -- # pgbench
   pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> pgbench -M prepared -f ./ins.sql -r -n -h $PGDATA -U postgres -T 60 -c 8 -j 2
   transaction type: Custom query
   scaling factor: 1
   query mode: prepared
   number of clients: 8
   number of threads: 2
   duration: 60 s
   number of transactions actually processed: 100862
   tps = 1680.570420 (including connections establishing)
   tps = 1680.946330 (excluding connections establishing)
   statement latencies in milliseconds:


   pg92@digoal-PowerEdge-R610-> cat analyze.sh 
   #!/bin/bash
   for ((i=0;i<100;i++))
   do
   psql -c "select * from analyze_log(1);"
   psql -c "select * from analyze_log(1000000);"
   done



   digoal=# select c1,count(*),to_char(crt_time,'yyyymmdd') from log group by c1,to_char(crt_time,'yyyymmdd') order by c1;
    c1 | count  | to_char  
   ----+--------+----------
     0 | 245002 | 20130426
     1 | 491034 | 20130426
     2 | 489717 | 20130426
     3 | 490628 | 20130426
     4 | 490064 | 20130426
     5 | 490393 | 20130426
     6 | 490893 | 20130426
     7 | 490081 | 20130426
     8 | 490180 | 20130426
     9 | 490659 | 20130426
    10 | 245860 | 20130426
   (11 rows)
   digoal=# select * from log_c1_cnt_day where cnt<>0 order by c1;
    c1 |  cnt   | stat_time 
   ----+--------+-----------
     0 | 245002 | 20130426
     1 | 491034 | 20130426
     2 | 489717 | 20130426
     3 | 490628 | 20130426
     4 | 490064 | 20130426
     5 | 490393 | 20130426
     6 | 490893 | 20130426
     7 | 490081 | 20130426
     8 | 490180 | 20130426
     9 | 490659 | 20130426
    10 | 245860 | 20130426
   (11 rows)
   ```