# How to estimate the row count of a PostgreSQL view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, count

I read the slow counting entry in the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting).
For my *tables* the estimates are quite accurate. For *views*, however

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl';
```

doesn't work and always return 0 records. Is there any way to count or estimate the rows of a view in Postgres other than this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someview;
```

`ANALYZE` did not work either for views (no problem for tables), I just get:

```
 ANALYZE v_myview;
 WARNING:  skipping "v_myview" --- cannot analyze non-tables or special system tables
 ANALYZE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query returns `0` because that's the correct answer.

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'someview';
```

A `VIEW` (unlike [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)) does not contain any rows. Internally, it's an empty table (0 rows) with a `ON SELECT DO INSTEAD` rule. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

> The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run
> every time the view is referenced in a query.

Consequently, `ANALYZE` is not applicable to views.
The system does not maintain rowcount estimates for views. Depending on the actual view definition you *may* be able to derive a number from estimates on underlying tables.

A `MATERIALIZED VIEW` might also be a **good solution**:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW someview_ct AS SELECT count(*) AS ct FROM someview;
```

Or base it on the actual view definition directly. Typically considerably cheaper than materializing the complete derived table. It's a snapshot, just like the estimates in `pg_class`, just more accurate immediately after a [`REFRESH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). You can run the expensive count once and reuse the result until you doubt it's still fresh enough.

Related:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274)

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation. However, I never doubted 0 was correct techically. Still though I wonder whether there's a way to figure out how many rows there are (or were) cause, count(*) does work for views. Are materialized views the only solution?

Comment: @MattBannert: Why would `count(*)` not work? It's potentially expensive, but is certainly works. BTW, the cheapest materialized view for the purpose would *be* `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS SELECT count(*) FROM someview;` (or use the actual view definition).

Comment: Oh yes, count does work, but I was looking for an alternative because it is actually expensive in my case.

Comment: @MattBannert: Actually, a MV with the count based on the view is probably the most elegant solution for you. Added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Thx  makes a lot of sense to me.