# Run a query with a LIMIT/OFFSET and also get the total number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pagination, limit

For pagination purposes, I need a run a query with the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses. But I also need a count of the number of rows that would be returned by that query without the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.

I want to run:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE /* whatever */ ORDER BY col1 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

And:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE /* whatever */
```

At the same time.  Is there a way to do that, particularly a way that lets Postgres optimize it, so that it's faster than running both individually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied)

Answer (score 348, accepted):

**Yes.** With a simple window function.

#### Add a column with the total count

```
SELECT *, count(*) OVER() AS full_count
FROM   tbl
WHERE  /* whatever */
ORDER  BY col1
OFFSET ?
LIMIT  ?
```

Be aware that the cost will be substantially higher than without the total number. Postgres has to actually *count all qualifying rows* either way, which imposes a cost depending on the total number. See:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

Two separate queries (one for the result set, one for the total count) may or may not be faster. But the overhead of executing two separate queries and processing results often tips the scales. Depends on the nature of the query, indexes, resources, cardinalities ...

**However**, [as Dani pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888375/run-a-query-with-a-limit-offset-and-also-get-the-total-number-of-rows/28888696?noredirect=1#comment88418369_28888696), when `OFFSET` is at least as great as the number of rows returned from the base query, no rows are returned. So we get no `full_count`, either. If that's a rare case, just run a second query for the count in this case.
If that's not acceptable, here is a **single query always returning the full count**, with a CTE and an `OUTER JOIN`. This adds more overhead and only makes sense for certain cases (expensive filters, few qualifying rows).

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  /* whatever */
   -- ORDER  BY col1 -- ①
   )
SELECT *
FROM  (
   TABLE  cte
   ORDER  BY col1
   LIMIT  ?
   OFFSET ?
   ) sub
RIGHT  JOIN (SELECT count(*) FROM cte) c(full_count) ON true;
```

① Typically it does not pay to add (the same) `ORDER BY` in the CTE. That forces all rows to be sorted. With `LIMIT`, typically only a small fraction has to be sorted (with "top-N heapsort").

You get one row of null values, with the `full_count` appended if `OFFSET` is too big. Else, it's appended to every row like in the first query.

If a row with all null values is a possible valid result you have to check `offset >= full_count` to disambiguate the origin of the empty row.

This still executes the base query only once. But it adds more overhead to the query and only pays if that's less than repeating the base query for the count.

Either way, the total count is returned with every row (redundantly). Doesn't add much cost. But if that's an issue, you could instead ...

#### Add a row with the total count

The added row must match the row type of the query result, and the count must fit into the data type of one of the columns. A bit of a hack. Like:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT col1, col2, int_col3
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  /* whatever */
   )
SELECT null AS col1, null AS col2, count(*)::int AS int_col3  -- maybe cast the count
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
TABLE  cte
ORDER  BY col1
LIMIT  ?
OFFSET ?
);
```

Again, sometimes it may be cheaper to just run a separate count (still in a single query!):

```sql
SELECT null AS col1, null AS col2, count(*)::int AS int_col3
FROM   tbl
WHERE  /* whatever */
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT col1, col2, int_col3
FROM   tbl
WHERE  /* whatever */
ORDER  BY col1
LIMIT  ?
OFFSET ?
);
```

About the syntax shortcut `TABLE tbl`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

Comment: By both LIMIT and conditions, we have rows to be returned, but with the given offset it would return no result. In that situation, How would we be able to get the row count?

Comment: very nice, thanks, works great when you using pagination , datatables,  just add this in start of your sql, and use it , save an extra query for total count.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this if the counting could be dynamically enabled in the query via an input parameter? I have a similar requirement but the user decides if he wants the inline count or not.

Comment: @julealgon: Please start a *new question* with the defining details. You can always link to this one for context and add leave a comment here to link back (and get my attention) if you wish.

Comment: For anyone wondering; if you also want to limit the COUNT(\*) done over the view, for example for when you have a huge table and want to prevent counting everything beyond a certain number, then you can use: COUNT(\*) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1000 FOLLOWING)
where 1000 is the number where the count will stop regardless of whether your query (without the LIMIT) would return even more rows

Comment: "but still cheaper than two separate queries" are you sure about that?
Because in my example with 12 million records the single query takes 6 times more time than 2 separate queries. (LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0)

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the exact query, but in my case, I find with Postgres 12 that the CTE version generates a very similar query plan to the non-CTE version, and is approximately as fast.

Comment: @JustinL.: The added overhead should only be significant for relatively cheap base queries. Also, Postgres 12 has improved CTE performance in multiple ways. (Though this CTE is still [`MATERIALIZED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) by default, being referenced twice.)

Comment: Using window function i added "count (*) filter (where [the same main where]) OVER() AS ..." to reflect the count of my main filter

Comment: @AnselmoMS: `count (*) OVER()` is applied *after* applying all filters (`WHERE` clauses) of the main query. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860. The aggregate `FILTER` clause only makes sense in this position to count a subset (apply *additional* filters).

Comment: What's the `c(full_count)` part at the end of the query? `c` appears to be an alias, but then it's invoked like a function?

Comment: @torkel: `(full_count)` is a list of *column* aliases, just one name in this case. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES): `FROM table_reference [AS] alias ( column1 [, column2 [, ...]] )`

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for how the TABLE keyword is used in this context?  I reviewed the sections on the "FROM clause" for select queries and table expressions.  I also reviewed most of the FROM clauses I could find in the manual, I still came up empty.

Comment: @user2959071: About `TABLE`, see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860

Comment: There is a way to achieve the same result, but without writing the query two times?

Comment: when you are ordering by col1 you are using col1 from cte... how can it use indexes if cte is just a temporary table created with the cte? genuine question

Comment: @91DarioDev: While the CTE is materialized (like in this case) indexes can only be used for the initial CTE, not in queries based on the materialized result. I updated a couple of things while being here.

Answer (score 18):

While [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter)'s answer works like a charm, it returns the total count of rows **in every row** like following:

```
col1 - col2 - col3 - total
--------------------------
aaaa - aaaa - aaaa - count
bbbb - bbbb - bbbb - count
cccc - cccc - cccc - count
```

You may want to consider using an approach that returns total count **only once**, like the following:

```
total - rows
------------
count - [{col1: 'aaaa'},{col2: 'aaaa'},{col3: 'aaaa'}
         {col1: 'bbbb'},{col2: 'bbbb'},{col3: 'bbbb'}
         {col1: 'cccc'},{col2: 'cccc'},{col3: 'cccc'}]
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM table
     WHERE /* sth */
    ) as count, 
    (SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE /* sth */
        ORDER BY col1
        OFFSET ?
        LIMIT ?
    ) AS t) AS rows
```

Comment: You'd also need to `WHERE` the `count(*)` subquery otherwise you'll just get the entire table count won't you?

Comment: @BenNeill you are right, I edited the answer to include your fix.

Answer (score 6):

edit: this answer is valid when retrieving the unfiltered table. I'll let it in case it could help someone but it might not exactly answer the initial question.

[Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888696/3585712)'s answer is perfect if you need an accurate value. However, on large tables you often only need a pretty good approximation. Postgres [gives you just that](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate) and it will be much faster as it will not need to evaluate each row:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE /* something */
    ORDER BY /* something */
    OFFSET ?
    LIMIT ?
    ) data
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl') pg_count(total_count) ON true;
```

I'm actually quite not sure if there is an advantage to externalize the `RIGHT JOIN` or have it as in a standard query. It would deserve some testing.

```
SELECT t.*, pgc.reltuples AS total_count
FROM tbl as t
RIGHT JOIN pg_class pgc ON pgc.relname = 'tbl'
WHERE /* something */
ORDER BY /* something */
OFFSET ?
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: About fast count estimate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860 Like you said: valid when retrieving the whole table - which is contradicted by the `WHERE` clause in your queries. The second query it logically wrong (retrieves one row for *every* table in the DB) - and more expensive when fixed.

Answer (score -22):

No.

There's perhaps some small gain you could theoretically gain over running them individually with enough complicated machinery under the hood. But, if you want to know how many rows match a condition you'll have to count them rather than just a LIMITed subset.