# mongodb - aggregation cursor count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was reading the API documentation (and was experimenting a bit), but it seems that `cursor.count()` no longer exists, so I was wondering if it was possible to get a count of your aggregate. This is because I would like to know how many documents there are in total, while still limiting and skipping results. I'm currently using $facet to facilitate this, but unsure if there's a better method.

```
{
    $facet: 
    {
        "results": 
        [
            {
                "$skip": 
                    start
            },
            {
                "$limit": 
                    finish
            },
        ],
        "total": 
        [
            {
                "$count": 
                    "total" 
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear:  you want the total count of the entire collection, not just the count of the skip-limit result (which has a natural upper bound of the limit)?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I want the count of the entire filtered aggregation for pagination purposes.

Comment: OK, so there may be a `{$match: expr}` before the `$facet`.   Your approach will correctly produce the count of the filtered agg plus skip-limit subset.

Comment: i was just wondering if there was an inbuilt cursor way. Just curious about performance.

Comment: There will be no performance issue either you use simple `.find()` query with the `skip() and limit()` cursor method or in the above `facet()` aggregation. May be the `$facet` will take some milliseconds more but that time will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$facet` for this use case is fine, both for style and performance.  It should be noted, though, that this is essentially two queries in one, albeit server-side optimized.  Getting the full count of the filtered material (or no filter at all if no initial `$match`) takes time regardless of the `$skip/$limit` setup.  If the `$match` produces a relatively small amount of material, then `$count` will be fast.  The dynamics involved are very similar to those in the regular SQL world, e.g. 
[Run a query with a LIMIT/OFFSET and also get the total number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888375/run-a-query-with-a-limit-offset-and-also-get-the-total-number-of-rows)