# How does one get the total rows for a partition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pagination, ecto

I'm using a windows function to help me pagination through a list of records in the database.

For example
I have a list of dogs and they all have a breed associated with them.
I want to show 10 dogs from each breed to my users.

So that would be

```
select * from dogs 
join (
SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY breed) as row_number FROM dogs
) rn on dogs.id = rn.id
where (row_number between 1 and 10)
```

That will give me ~ten dogs from each breed..

What I need though is a count.  Is there a way to get the count of the partitions. I want to know how many Staffies I have waiting for adoption.

I do notice that there's a percentage and all the docs I find seem to indicate theres something called total rows. But I don't see it.

Comment: No. There is not a percentage of docs that *indicate there's something called total rows*, because it does not exist. What you find is that there are a percentage of docs that **generate** a column aliased as total_rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run the window aggregate function `count()` over the same partition (without adding `ORDER BY`!) to get the total count for the partition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY breed ORDER BY id) AS rn
        , count() OVER (PARTITION BY breed) AS breed_count          -- !
   FROM   dogs
   ) sub
WHERE  rn < 11;
```

Also removed the unnecessary join and simplified.
See:

- [Run a query with a LIMIT/OFFSET and also get the total number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888375/run-a-query-with-a-limit-offset-and-also-get-the-total-number-of-rows/28888696#28888696)

And I added `ORDER BY` to the frame definition of `row_number()` to get a deterministic result. Without, Postgres is free to return any 10 arbitrary rows. Any write to the table (or `VACUUM`, etc.) can and will change the result without `ORDER BY`.

Aside, pagination with `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` does not scale well. Consider:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

Comment: table will never have more than 8k records.. But yeah 
What got me was that I'd put the order by on the count too.  It broke a pile of things