# How to improve the performance of counting all rows

Tags: postgresql, count, query-optimization

I use the SQL like this :

TableA have 2 million records, search the count speed 25.1secs.

```
select count(*) from TableA;
```

TableA have 2 million records, TableB also have 2 million records, get the count of TableA and TableB speed 3mins.

How to Increase the search efficiency?

Comment: So what is your query to "get the count of tablea and tableb"? 25 seconds for just 2 million rows seems awfully slow. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for both tables (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`** both queries. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code in comments

Answer (score 3):

Many different ways to achieve this:

[Slow counting](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)

[Involving triggers](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/) (a rather lengthier approach, but an efficient one)

[Getting close estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table/7945274#7945274) rather than getting the exact count speeds up the process.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have exact precision for the number of rows ?
If not, you can use the pg_stat_user view that will give you an good estimation.

```
 SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
 FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
 WHERE relname='TableA'
 AND schemaname='yourSchema'
```