# Counting unread news in a large table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, query-performance, postgresql-performance, postgresql-10

I got a pretty common (at least as I think) database structure: there are news
(`News(id, source_id)`), each news has a source (`Source(id, url)`). Sources are aggregated to topics (`Topic(id, title)`) via `TopicSource(source_id, topic_id)`. In addition there are users (`User(id, name)`) which can mark news as read via `NewsRead(news_id, user_id)`. Here is a diagram to clear things up:
[image: db diagram]

I want to **count unread news in topics for specific user**. The problem is `News` table is a big one (10^6 - 10^7 rows). Fortunately, I don't need to know *exact* count, it's ok to stop counting after a threshold returning this threshold as a counted value.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274) for a **one topic** I came up with a following query:

```sql
SELECT t.topic_id, count(1) as unread_count
FROM (
 SELECT 1, topic_id
 FROM news n
   JOIN topic_source t ON n.source_id = t.source_id
   -- join news_read to filter already read news
   LEFT JOIN news_read r
     ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
 WHERE t.topic_id = 3 AND r.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 10 -- Threshold
) t GROUP BY t.topic_id;
```

([query plan 1](https://explain.depesz.com/s/mlqe)). This query takes about 50 ms on test db which is acceptable.

Now a want to select unread count for **multiple topics**. I tried to select like that:

```sql
SELECT
  t.topic_id,
  (SELECT count(1)
   FROM (SELECT 1 FROM news n
          JOIN topic_source tt ON n.source_id = tt.source_id
          LEFT JOIN news_read r
            ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
          WHERE tt.topic_id = t.topic_id AND r.user_id IS NULL
          LIMIT 10 -- Threshold
        ) t) AS unread_count
FROM topic_source t WHERE t.topic_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY t.topic_id;
```

([query plan 2](https://explain.depesz.com/s/U4Dj)). But for the reason unknown to me it takes about 1.5 s on test data while sum of individual queries should get about 0.2-0.3 s.

I'm clearly missing something here. Is there a mistake in second query? Is there a better (faster) way to select a count of unread news?

**Additional info:**

- Here is a [fiddle with DB structure and queries](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n8EwywZJpQtYV5AvSznaC/2).
- I'm using PostgresSQL 10 with SQLAlchemy (but raw SQL is ok for now).

Table sizes:

```
News - 10^6 - 10^7
User - 10^3
Source - 10^4
Topic - 10^3
TopicSource - 10^5
NewsRead - 10^6
```

**UPD:** query plans clearly show I messed up second query. Any cues are appreciated.

**UPD2:** I tried this query with lateral join which is supposed to simply run first (the fastest one) query for each `topic_id`:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  count(*)
FROM topic t
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT ts.topic_id
     FROM news n
       LEFT JOIN news_read r
         ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
       JOIN topic_source ts ON n.source_id = ts.source_id
     WHERE ts.topic_id = t.id AND r.user_id IS NULL
     LIMIT 10
) p ON TRUE
WHERE t.id IN (4, 10, 12, 16)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

([query plan 3](https://explain.depesz.com/s/p21L)). But it seems that Pg planner has different opinion on this - it runs very slow seq scans and hash joins instead of index scans and merge joins.

Comment: I wonder how [this](https://paste.ofcode.org/TMhZbxCGqiSgc3ijhzZwfX) query would fare on your data. I tried creating similar volumes of sample data as yours, but since the distributions are so different I get very different results even for your original queries; for example the multi topic query only takes ~19ms (best out of many).

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thank you for suggestion! This query takes ~3.5s on my data. I guess our distributions are way off. [Explain is here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/q740). Suddenly it appears that multiple `UNION ALL` are very fast. I will update my post after short research.

Comment: I noticed that I forgot the LIMIT 10 from the innermost sub query. That's what you get for copying just some of the many attempts. Perhaps it'd run a bit faster with that in place.

Comment: Ah, I missed that as well. Adding `LIMIT` do help but some strange behaviour appears: `LIMIT 10` works very fast - 25ms max as well as `LIMIT 20`. `LIMIT 100` - ~1.2s cold one and ~0.7s subsequent ones. `LIMIT 1` runs more than 2 seconds - I don't even think I understand something now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some benchmarking I've finally stopped on simple *UNION ALL* query and it's ten times faster than lateral join on my data:

```sql
SELECT
  p.topic_id,
  count(*)
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT fs.topic_id
              FROM news n
                LEFT JOIN news_read r
                  ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
                JOIN topic_source fs ON n.source_id = fs.source_id
              WHERE fs.topic_id = 4 AND r.user_id IS NULL
              LIMIT 100
            ) t1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT fs.topic_id
              FROM news n
                LEFT JOIN news_read r
                  ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
                JOIN topic_source fs ON n.source_id = fs.source_id
              WHERE fs.topic_id = 10 AND r.user_id IS NULL
              LIMIT 100
            ) t1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT fs.topic_id
              FROM news n
                LEFT JOIN news_read r
                  ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
                JOIN topic_source fs ON n.source_id = fs.source_id
              WHERE fs.topic_id = 12 AND r.user_id IS NULL
              LIMIT 100
            ) t1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT fs.topic_id
              FROM news n
                LEFT JOIN news_read r
                  ON (n.id = r.news_id AND r.user_id = 1)
                JOIN topic_source fs ON n.source_id = fs.source_id
              WHERE fs.topic_id = 16 AND r.user_id IS NULL
              LIMIT 100
            ) t1
     ) p
GROUP BY p.topic_id;
```

([execute plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/92pN))

Intuition here is that by specifying topic_id`s explicitly one provide Pg planner with enough information to build an effective plan.

From `SQLAlchemy` point of view it's pretty straightforward:

```python
# topic_ids, user_id are defined elsewhere, e.g.
# topic_ids = [4, 10, 12, 16]
# user_id = 1
for topic_id in topic_ids:
    topic_query = (
        db.session.query(News.id, TopicSource.topic_id)
        .join(TopicSource, TopicSource.source_id == News.source_id)
        # LEFT JOIN NewsRead table to filter only unreads
        # (where News.user_id IS NULL)
        .outerjoin(NewsRead,
                   and_(NewsRead.news_id == News.id,
                        NewsRead.user_id == user_id))
        .filter(TopicSource.topic_id == topic_id,
                NewsRead.user_id.is_(None))
        .limit(100))
    topic_queries.append(topic_query)
# Unite queries with UNION ALL
union_query = topic_queries[0].union_all(*topic_queries[1:])
# Groups query by `topic_id` and count unreads
counts = (union_query
          # Using `with_entities(func.count())` to avoid
          # a subquery.  See link below for info:
          # https://gist.github.com/hest/8798884
          .with_entities(TopicSource.topic_id.label('topic_id'),
                         func.count().label('unread_count'))
          .group_by(TopicSource.topic_id))
result = counts.all()
```