# Optimizing SELECT count(*) on large table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-parallel-query

Basic count on a large table on PostgreSQL 14 with 64GB Ram & 20 threads. Storage is an NVME disk.

Questions:

- How do I improve the query for this select count query? What kind of optimizations should I look into on Postgres configuration?
- The workers planned is 4 but launched 0, is that normal?

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT count(*) FROM public.product;
```

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2691545.69..2691545.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=330901.439..330902.951 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1963080 read=1140455 dirtied=1908 written=111146
  I/O Timings: read=36692.273 write=6548.923
  ->  Gather  (cost=2691545.27..2691545.68 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=330901.342..330902.861 rows=1 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=1963080 read=1140455 dirtied=1908 written=111146
        I/O Timings: read=36692.273 write=6548.923
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2690545.27..2690545.28 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=330898.747..330898.757 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1963080 read=1140455 dirtied=1908 written=111146
              I/O Timings: read=36692.273 write=6548.923
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using points on products  (cost=0.57..2634234.99 rows=22524114 width=0) (actual time=0.361..222958.361 rows=90993600 loops=1)
                    Heap Fetches: 46261956
                    Buffers: shared hit=1963080 read=1140455 dirtied=1908 written=111146
                    I/O Timings: read=36692.273 write=6548.923
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=39 read=8
  I/O Timings: read=0.398
Planning Time: 2.561 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 4
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 0.691 ms, Inlining 104.789 ms, Optimization 24.169 ms, Emission 22.457 ms, Total 152.107 ms
Execution Time: 330999.777 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The workers planned is 4 but launched 0, is that normal?

It can happen when too many concurrent transactions compete for a limited number of allowed parallel workers. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/how-parallel-query-works.html)

> The number of background workers that the planner will consider using
> is limited to at most [**`max_parallel_workers_per_gather`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS-PER-GATHER). The
> total number of background workers that can exist at any one time is
> limited by both [**`max_worker_processes`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-WORKER-PROCESSES) and
> [**`max_parallel_workers`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS). Therefore, it is possible for a
> parallel query to run with fewer workers than planned, or even with no
> workers at all. The optimal plan may depend on the number of workers
> that are available, so this can result in poor query performance. If
> this occurrence is frequent, consider increasing
> `max_worker_processes` and `max_parallel_workers` so that more workers
> can be run simultaneously or alternatively reducing
> `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` so that the planner requests fewer
> workers.

You can also optimize overall performance to free up resources, or get better hardware (in addition to ramping up `max_parallel_workers`).

What's also troubling:

> Heap Fetches: 46261956

For 90993600 rows. That's way too many for comfort. An index-only scan is not supposed to do that many heap fetches.

Both of these symptoms would indicate massive concurrent write access (or long-running transactions hogging resources and keeping [**`autovacuum`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) from doing its job). Look into that, and/or tune per-table `autovacuum` settings for table `product` to be more aggressive, so that columns statistics are more valid and the visibility map can keep up. See:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21649/3684)

Also, with halfway valid table statistics, a (blazingly fast!) **estimate** might be good enough? See:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274)

Comment: @CodeGuru: Also note the added bit about estimates.