# Is estimated row count accurate when only inserts are done in a table?

Tags: postgresql, count, rowcount, autovacuum

We use PostgreSQL for analytics. Three typical operations we do on tables are:

- Create table as select
- Create table followed by insert in table
- Drop table

We are not doing any `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc.

For this situation can we assume that estimates would just be accurate?

```
SELECT reltuples AS estimate FROM pg_class where relname = 'mytable';
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`autovacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) running (which is the default), `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM` are fired up automatically - both of which update `reltuples`. Basic configuration parameters for `ANALYZE` (which typically runs more often), ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-ANALYZE-THRESHOLD)):

> `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` (`integer`)
>
> Specifies the minimum number of inserted, updated or deleted tuples
> needed to trigger an `ANALYZE` in any one table. The default is 50
> tuples. This parameter can only be set in the `postgresql.conf` file
> or on the server command line; but the setting can be overridden for
> individual tables by changing table storage parameters.
>
> `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` (`floating point`)
>
> Specifies a fraction of the table size to add to
> `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` when deciding whether to trigger an
> `ANALYZE`. The default is 0.1 (10% of table size). This parameter can
> only be set in the `postgresql.conf` file or on the server command
> line; but the setting can be overridden for individual tables by
> changing table storage parameters.

[Another quote gives insight to details:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html)

> For efficiency reasons, `reltuples` and `relpages` are not updated
> on-the-fly, and so they usually contain somewhat out-of-date values.
> They are updated by `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and a few DDL commands such
> as `CREATE INDEX`. A `VACUUM` or `ANALYZE` operation that does not
> scan the entire table (which is commonly the case) will incrementally
> update the `reltuples` count on the basis of the part of the table it
> did scan, resulting in an approximate value. In any case, the planner
> will scale the values it finds in `pg_class` to match the current
> physical table size, thus obtaining a closer approximation.

Estimates are up to date accordingly. You can change `autovacuum` settings to be more aggressive. You can even do this per table. See:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21649/3684)

On top of that, you can scale estimates like Postgres itself does it. See:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274)

Note that `VACUUM` (of secondary relevance to your case) wasn't triggered by only `INSERT`s before Postgres 13. Quoting the release notes:

> - Allow inserts, not only updates and deletes, to trigger vacuuming
>   activity in [**`autovacuum`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) (Laurenz Albe, Darafei
>   Praliaskouski)
>
>   Previously, insert-only activity would trigger auto-analyze but not
>   auto-vacuum, on the grounds that there could not be any dead tuples to
>   remove. However, a vacuum scan has other useful side-effects such as
>   setting page-all-visible bits, which improves the efficiency of
>   index-only scans. Also, allowing an insert-only table to receive
>   periodic vacuuming helps to spread out the work of “freezing” old
>   tuples, so that there is not suddenly a large amount of freezing work
>   to do when the entire table reaches the anti-wraparound threshold all
>   at once.
>
>   If necessary, this behavior can be adjusted with the new parameters
>   [**`autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-INSERT-THRESHOLD) and
>   [**`autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-INSERT-SCALE-FACTOR), or the equivalent
>   table storage options.

Comment: So autovacuum_analyze_threshold (integer) with integer being 50, can one assume that the maximum inaacuracy would be of 50 rows at any time? (assuming auto vacuum didn't finish)?
If the insertion rate is quite fast but autovaccum_analyze_threshold is like 50, does the whole insertion operation toggle between insertion and vacumming every 50 tuples?

Comment: @PankajLal: No, no, no. That's not how it works. That threshold is used when `autovacuum` awakes and checks the table. It's not an instant trigger. Also, (scaled) estimates are typically pretty good, but they are just that: estimates, based on a sample. Postgres does not *count* big tables all the time, that would be way too expensive. That's up to you if you need an exact count. But remember that every count is an estimate. With concurrent write activity, it may be outdated on arrival.