# SQL limit with spread

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-limit

Is there a way to limit a selection like with `LIMIT`, but instead of returning the limitation with an offset, limit with a "spread".

So for instance if a select returns 1000 rows and I limit it to 100, then I get every 10th row from start to end.

I know this would require the full `SELECT` to be performed since the RDBMS would need to go through all rows to do so. But instead of, for instance, returning 100000 rows when I need every 100th row, there would be a lot less transfer and the work could be done at the RDBMS.

I am requiring this on a PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: "...get every 10th row from start to end..." -- In the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause there's no "first row", "middle row" or "end row". The engine can return the rows in any order, and this is subject to change in every query execution without notice. The question doesn't make sense as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in syntax to do that in connection with [`LIMIT` / `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) (nor with standard-SQL `FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ count ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }]`).

You can achieve your goal with the [modulo operator **`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, ... original SELECT list
   FROM ... -- original query
   ) sub
WHERE rn%10 = 0  -- every 10th row
```

Since there is no `ORDER BY` in the window definition, row numbers are assigned according to the `ORDER BY` of the query.
If there is *no* `ORDER BY` at all, you get an *arbitrary* order of rows. That's still some kind of order, the result is just out of your hands.

You can apply that kind of filter ***on an individual table*** with the [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10);  -- roughly 10 %
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10);  -- roughly 10 %
```

`SYSTEM` is faster, `BERNOULLI` is more random.

You could even apply the `TABLESAMPLE` filter on multiple tables in the same query, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10)
JOIN tbl2 TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10) USING (big_id);
```

But the number of resulting rows can vary wildly. To get a given number of rows, consider the additional module [`tsm_system_rows`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tsm-system-rows.html) instead. See:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274)
- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)