# How do I measure progress while streaming a postgres database query via pg-query-stream?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-streams, bullmq

I have an ETL query which requires me to read a large number of rows and then apply some transformation on them and save them back to a separate table in Postgres. I am using pg-query-stream and I plan to run the test function below inside a bullmq job.

**How do I measure progress** (current rows processed / total number of rows) for the given stream below?

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const QueryStream = require('pg-query-stream');

function test() {
  const pool = new Pool({
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    ssl: process.env.POSTGRES_SSL === 'true',
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  });
  const query = `
    SELECT 
        feed_item_id, 
        title, 
        summary, 
        content 
    FROM 
        feed_items 
    ORDER BY 
        pubdate DESC, 
        feed_item_id
    LIMIT 50
    `;

  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const queryStream = new QueryStream(query, [], {
      batchSize: 200,
    });
    const stream = client.query(queryStream);
    console.log(stream);
    stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify());
    stream.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      done();
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('stream has ended');
      done();
    });
    stream.on('data', async (row) => {
      stream.pause();
      console.log('data received', row.feed_item_id);
      //   const progress = index / ???
      //   Simulate async task
      await timeout(10);
      stream.resume();
    });
  });
}

test();
```

Comment: Should be very easy via [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator), because you  can control every next-row read.

Comment: @vitaly-t i l definitely take a look into this one, thank you for the headsup

Answer (score 1):

To do that you'll need to first get count of the rows in the table.
You can do it as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/3302263).

And with that count you can pipe `QueryStream` into another stream and measure progress there:

```
const Stream = require('stream')

class ProgressStream extends Stream.Writable{
  constructor(total) {
    super();
    this.i = 0;
    this.total = total;
  }

  _write(chunk, enc, done) {
    this.i++;
    if (this.i % 100 === 1) {
      console.log(`Processed ${this.i} out of ${this.total} of rows`);
    }
    done();
  }
}

const progressStream = new ProgressStream(count);
progressStream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log(`All ${progressStream.i} rows processed!`)
});

stream.pipe(progressStream);
```