# supabase postgres efficient count request

Tags: postgresql, count, supabase

I'm developing a feed reader app with supabase. A simplified schema would be :

```
Table Categories
   id bigint (primary key)

Table Feeds
   id text (primary key),
   read_at timestamp with time zone null
   category_id bigint (foreign key btree index)
```

I would like to have the count of unread feeds by category.
At first I've simply created a view. On the client side, I refresh the feeds, then I get the categories with :

```
create view
  categories_view as
select
  categories.id,
  (
    select
      count(*) as count
    from
      feeds
    where
      feeds.read_at is null
      and feeds.category_id = categories.id
  ) as unread_feeds
from
  categories;
```

But as the database grows it becomes increasingly slower because of this count method.
My goal is that the client is always up to date with that count. When I refresh the feeds I want the right count, but I also want it when I read the feeds (whether it is one, many of one category or many of several categories at the time).

I read from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql) that using `pg_class` is the most efficient way to count but I need to count only the unread feeds, not all.

I can think of several solutions but I'd like your advices on how can I handle this the most efficient way.

- Separate the feeds table in two tables, unreadFeeds and readFeeds, so I can use the `pg_class` count, but it feels quit wrong, I would have to constantly move the data. And would this count be up to date right after I've updated the data?
- Store a count column in the categories table, which I would manually update every time I get new feeds and a feed is read. Seems a bit complicated (and potentially worst efficient?)
- A magic query that I didn't think of ? And that's why I need you :)

Comment: See [Count estimate](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate).

Comment: Thanks I think that this function is what I needed!